# How to access .mm file from framework in xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have successfully managed to integrate framework(that contains .mm files) in my Xcode project and it was working absolutely fine. But a tragedy happened with me and my Mac became out of order due to which I have lost all my data(The files from which i have made my framework) and now framework is working fine in the project but i want to access the .mm files from my framework.How can i do that kindly assist if you can...

Comment: No, I'm afraid you can't unmake the sausage.  Backup, version control. These are your friends